# Enterprise search timeout for Elasticsearch create index

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, timeout, kubernetes-operator, elastic-enterprise-search

I am using [ECK](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/index.html) to deploy Elasticsearch cluster on Kubernetes.

My Elasticsearch is working fine and it shows `green` as cluster. But when Enterprise search start and start creating `indexes` in Elasticsearch, after creating some indexes, it give error for timeout.

**pv.yaml**

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-master
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /mnt/nfs/kubernetes/elasticsearch/master/
...
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-data
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /mnt/nfs/kubernetes/elasticsearch/data/
...
```

**multi_node.yaml**

```
---
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: bselastic
spec:
  version: 8.1.2
  nodeSets:
  - name: masters
    count: 1
    config:
      node.roles: ["master",
#                  "data",
                  ]
      xpack.ml.enabled: true
    # Volumeclaim needed to add volume, it was giving error for not volume claim
    # and its not starting pod.
    volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: elasticsearch-data # Do not change this name unless you set up a volume mount for the data path.
      spec:
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 5Gi
        storageClassName: standard
  - name: data-node
    count: 1
    config:
      node.roles: ["data", "ingest"]
    volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: elasticsearch-data
      spec:
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 5Gi
        storageClassName: standard
...
---
apiVersion: enterprisesearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: EnterpriseSearch
metadata:
  name: enterprise-search-bselastic
spec:
  version: 8.1.3
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: bselastic
  podTemplate:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: enterprise-search
        env:
        - name: JAVA_OPTS
          value: -Xms2g -Xmx2g
        - name: "elasticsearch.startup_retry.interval"
          value: "30"
        - name: allow_es_settings_modification
          value: "true"
...
```

Apply these changes using below command.

`kubectl apply -f multi_node.yaml -n deleteme -f pv.yaml`

Check the Elasticsearch cluster status

```
# kubectl get es -n deleteme
NAME        HEALTH    NODES   VERSION   PHASE             AGE
bselastic   unknown           8.1.2     ApplyingChanges   47s
```

Check all pods

```
# kubectl get pod -n deleteme
NAME                                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
bselastic-es-data-node-0                           0/1     Running   0          87s
bselastic-es-masters-0                             1/1     Running   0          87s
enterprise-search-bselastic-ent-54675f95f8-9sskf   0/1     Running   0          86s
```

Elasticsearch cluster become green after 7+ min

```
[root@1175014-kubemaster01 nilesh]# kubectl get es -n deleteme
NAME        HEALTH   NODES   VERSION   PHASE   AGE
bselastic   green    2       8.1.2     Ready   7m30s
```

enterprise search log

```
# kubectl -n deleteme logs -f enterprise-search-bselastic-ent-549bbcb9-rnhmc
Custom Enterprise Search configuration file detected, not overwriting it (any settings passed via environment will be ignored)
Found java executable in PATH
Java version detected: 11.0.14.1 (major version: 11)
Enterprise Search is starting...
[2022-04-25T16:34:22.282+00:00][7][2000][app-server][INFO]: Elastic Enterprise Search version=8.1.3, JRuby version=9.2.16.0, Ruby version=2.5.7, Rails version=5.2.6
[2022-04-25T16:34:23.862+00:00][7][2000][app-server][INFO]: Performing pre-flight checks for Elasticsearch running on https://bselastic-es-http.deleteme.svc:9200...
[2022-04-25T16:34:25.308+00:00][7][2000][app-server][WARN]: [pre-flight] Failed to connect to Elasticsearch backend. Make sure it is running and healthy.
[2022-04-25T16:34:25.310+00:00][7][2000][app-server][INFO]: [pre-flight] Error: /usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/shared_togo/lib/shared_togo/elasticsearch_checks.class:187: Connection refused (Connection refused) (Faraday::ConnectionFailed)

[2022-04-25T16:34:31.353+00:00][7][2000][app-server][WARN]: [pre-flight] Failed to connect to Elasticsearch backend. Make sure it is running and healthy.
[2022-04-25T16:34:31.355+00:00][7][2000][app-server][INFO]: [pre-flight] Error: /usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/shared_togo/lib/shared_togo/elasticsearch_checks.class:187: Connection refused (Connection refused) (Faraday::ConnectionFailed)

[2022-04-25T16:34:37.370+00:00][7][2000][app-server][WARN]: [pre-flight] Failed to connect to Elasticsearch backend. Make sure it is running and healthy.
[2022-04-25T16:34:37.372+00:00][7][2000][app-server][INFO]: [pre-flight] Error: /usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/shared_togo/lib/shared_togo/elasticsearch_checks.class:187: Connection refused (Connection refused) (Faraday::ConnectionFailed)

[2022-04-25T16:34:43.384+00:00][7][2000][app-server][WARN]: [pre-flight] Failed to connect to Elasticsearch backend. Make sure it is running and healthy.
[2022-04-25T16:34:43.386+00:00][7][2000][app-server][INFO]: [pre-flight] Error: /usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/shared_togo/lib/shared_togo/elasticsearch_checks.class:187: Connection refused (Connection refused) (Faraday::ConnectionFailed)

[2022-04-25T16:34:49.400+00:00][7][2000][app-server][WARN]: [pre-flight] Failed to connect to Elasticsearch backend. Make sure it is running and healthy.
[2022-04-25T16:34:49.401+00:00][7][2000][app-server][INFO]: [pre-flight] Error: /usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/shared_togo/lib/shared_togo/elasticsearch_checks.class:187: Connection refused (Connection refused) (Faraday::ConnectionFailed)
[2022-04-25T16:37:56.290+00:00][7][2000][app-server][INFO]: [pre-flight] Elasticsearch cluster is ready
[2022-04-25T16:37:56.292+00:00][7][2000][app-server][INFO]: [pre-flight] Successfully connected to Elasticsearch
[2022-04-25T16:37:56.367+00:00][7][2000][app-server][INFO]: [pre-flight] Successfully loaded Elasticsearch plugin information for all nodes
[2022-04-25T16:37:56.381+00:00][7][2000][app-server][INFO]: [pre-flight] Elasticsearch running with an active basic license
[2022-04-25T16:37:56.423+00:00][7][2000][app-server][INFO]: [pre-flight] Elasticsearch API key service is enabled
[2022-04-25T16:37:56.446+00:00][7][2000][app-server][INFO]: [pre-flight] Elasticsearch will be used for authentication
[2022-04-25T16:37:56.447+00:00][7][2000][app-server][INFO]: Elasticsearch looks healthy and configured correctly to run Enterprise Search
[2022-04-25T16:37:56.452+00:00][7][2000][app-server][INFO]: Performing pre-flight checks for Kibana running on http://localhost:5601...
[2022-04-25T16:37:56.482+00:00][7][2000][app-server][WARN]: [pre-flight] Failed to connect to Kibana backend. Make sure it is running and healthy.
[2022-04-25T16:37:56.486+00:00][7][2000][app-server][ERROR]: Could not connect to Kibana backend after 0 seconds.
[2022-04-25T16:37:56.488+00:00][7][2000][app-server][WARN]: Enterprise Search is unable to connect to Kibana. Ensure it is running at http://localhost:5601 for user deleteme-enterprise-search-bselastic-ent-user.
[2022-04-25T16:37:59.344+00:00][7][2000][app-server][INFO]: Elastic APM agent is disabled
{"timestamp": "2022-04-25T16:38:05+00:00", "message": "readiness probe failed", "curl_rc": "7"}
{"timestamp": "2022-04-25T16:38:06+00:00", "message": "readiness probe failed", "curl_rc": "7"}
{"timestamp": "2022-04-25T16:38:16+00:00", "message": "readiness probe failed", "curl_rc": "7"}
{"timestamp": "2022-04-25T16:38:26+00:00", "message": "readiness probe failed", "curl_rc": "7"}
{"timestamp": "2022-04-25T16:38:36+00:00", "message": "readiness probe failed", "curl_rc": "7"}
[2022-04-25T16:38:43.880+00:00][7][2000][app-server][INFO]: [db_lock] [installation] Status: [Starting] Ensuring migrations tracking index exists
{"timestamp": "2022-04-25T16:38:45+00:00", "message": "readiness probe failed", "curl_rc": "7"}
{"timestamp": "2022-04-25T16:38:56+00:00", "message": "readiness probe failed", "curl_rc": "7"}
[2022-04-25T16:39:05.283+00:00][7][2000][app-server][INFO]: [db_lock] [installation] Status: [Finished] Ensuring migrations tracking index exists
[2022-04-25T16:39:05.782+00:00][7][2000][app-server][INFO]: [db_lock] [installation] Status: [Starting] Creating indices for 38 models
[2022-05-02T16:21:47.303+00:00][8][2000][es][DEBUG]: {
"request": {
    "url": "https://bselastic-es-http.deleteme.svc:9200/.ent-search-actastic-oauth_applications_v2",
    "method": "put",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "[FILTERED]",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-elastic-product-origin": "enterprise-search",
      "User-Agent": "Faraday v1.8.0"
    },
    "params": null,
    "body": "{\"settings\":{\"index\":{\"hidden\":true,\"refresh_interval\":-1},\"number_of_shards\":1,\"auto_expand_replicas\":\"0-3\",\"priority\":250},\"mappings\":{\"dynamic\":\"strict\",\"properties\":{\"id\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"created_at\":{\"type\":\"date\"},\"updated_at\":{\"type\":\"date\"},\"name\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"uid\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"secret\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"redirect_uri\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"scopes\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"confidential\":{\"type\":\"boolean\"},\"app_type\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"}}},\"aliases\":{}}"
  },
  "exception": "/usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/lib/swiftype/es/client.class:28: Read timed out (Faraday::TimeoutError)\n",
  "duration": 30042.3,
  "stack": [
    "lib/actastic/schema.class:172:in `create_index!'",
    "lib/actastic/schema.class:195:in `create_index_and_mapping!'",
    "shared_togo/lib/shared_togo.class:894:in `block in apply_actastic_migrations'",
    "shared_togo/lib/shared_togo.class:892:in `block in each'",
    "shared_togo/lib/shared_togo.class:892:in `block in apply_actastic_migrations'",
    "lib/db_lock.class:182:in `with_status'",
    "shared_togo/lib/shared_togo.class:891:in `apply_actastic_migrations'",
    "shared_togo/lib/shared_togo.class:406:in `block in install!'",
    "lib/db_lock.class:171:in `with_lock'",
    "shared_togo/lib/shared_togo.class:399:in `install!'",
    "config/application.class:102:in `block in Application'",
    "config/environment.class:9:in `<main>'",
    "config/environment.rb:1:in `<main>'",
    "shared_togo/lib/shared_togo/cli/command.class:37:in `initialize'",
    "shared_togo/lib/shared_togo/cli/command.class:10:in `run_and_exit'",
    "shared_togo/lib/shared_togo/cli.class:143:in `run_supported_command'",
    "shared_togo/lib/shared_togo/cli.class:125:in `run_command'",
    "shared_togo/lib/shared_togo/cli.class:112:in `run!'",
    "bin/enterprise-search-internal:15:in `<main>'"
  ]
}
[2022-04-25T16:55:21.340+00:00][7][2000][app-server][INFO]: [db_lock] [installation] Status: [Failed] Creating indices for 38 models: Error = Faraday::TimeoutError: Read timed out
Unexpected exception while running Enterprise Search:
Error: Read timed out at
```

Master node logs

```
# kubectl -n deleteme logs -f bselastic-es-masters-0
Skipping security auto configuration because the configuration file [/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml] is missing or is not a regular file

{"@timestamp":"2022-04-25T16:55:11.051Z", "log.level": "INFO",  "current.health":"GREEN","message":"Cluster health status changed from [YELLOW] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[.ent-search-actastic-search_relevance_suggestions-document_position_id-unique-constraint][0]]]).","previous.health":"YELLOW","reason":"shards started [[.ent-search-actastic-search_relevance_suggestions-document_position_id-unique-constraint][0]]" , "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[bselastic-es-masters-0][masterService#updateTask][T#1]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.AllocationService","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"rnaZmz4kQwOBNbWau43wYA","elasticsearch.node.id":"YMyOM1umSL22ro86II6Ymw","elasticsearch.node.name":"bselastic-es-masters-0","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"bselastic"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-04-25T16:55:21.447Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"writing cluster state took [10525ms] which is above the warn threshold of [10s]; [skipped writing] global metadata, wrote metadata for [0] new indices and [1] existing indices, removed metadata for [0] indices and skipped [48] unchanged indices", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[bselastic-es-masters-0][generic][T#5]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.gateway.PersistedClusterStateService","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"rnaZmz4kQwOBNbWau43wYA","elasticsearch.node.id":"YMyOM1umSL22ro86II6Ymw","elasticsearch.node.name":"bselastic-es-masters-0","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"bselastic"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-04-25T16:55:21.448Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"after [10.3s] publication of cluster state version [226] is still waiting for {bselastic-es-masters-0}{YMyOM1umSL22ro86II6Ymw}{ljGkLdk-RAukc9NEJtQCVw}{192.168.88.213}{192.168.88.213:9300}{m}{k8s_node_name=1175027-kubeworker15.sb.rackspace.com, xpack.installed=true} [SENT_APPLY_COMMIT], {bselastic-es-data-node-0}{K88khDyfRwaGCBZwMKEaHA}{g9mXrT4WTumoj09W1OylYA}{192.168.88.214}{192.168.88.214:9300}{di}{k8s_node_name=1175027-kubeworker15.sb.rackspace.com, xpack.installed=true} [SENT_PUBLISH_REQUEST]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[bselastic-es-masters-0][generic][T#1]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.cluster.coordination.Coordinator.CoordinatorPublication","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"rnaZmz4kQwOBNbWau43wYA","elasticsearch.node.id":"YMyOM1umSL22ro86II6Ymw","elasticsearch.node.name":"bselastic-es-masters-0","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"bselastic"}
```

Which attribute we have to set in Enterprise search to increase timeout ? or is there any way to get debug log for Enterprise search ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to increase the default timeout Globally parameter by following this example:

```
es = Elasticsearch(timeout=30, max_retries=10, retry_on_timeout=True)
```

This would help to give the cluster more time to respond.

Comment: creating connection is not in my control, enterprise search create internally from the POD.